# Issue with AWS S3 cli uploading after it shows in bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

My goal is to automate uploading large video files to s3 via cli which can range from ~800MB to 10GB+. I have no issues with files below ~4GB, but anything larger and I'll usually run into an issue where the video will be uploaded to S3 but the cli will be stuck in an upload loop forever with that video. I am running the cli via Node in a child_process.exec command, and watch the processes to see when the cli is done before moving on to the next video in the queue. Command I'm running:

```
`aws s3 cp temp.mkv s3://holochive/"${videoToUpload.channel}"/"${videoToUpload.title}" --expected-size=15000000000 --storage-class STANDARD_IA --metadata '{"id": "${videoToUpload.id}", "published": "${videoToUpload.published}", "thumbnail": "${videoToUpload.thumbnail}"}'`
```

When I ran a debug for a large file solo, I got a lot of errors saying it needed to be retried, but it seems to be fine after. Not sure if this could be some network shenanigans, a config issue, or just an issue with large files, and any advice/direction would be appreciated. There is this section that might be an actual issue but it's really hard to tell from the log:

```
2020-08-07 20:22:29,771 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.CompleteMultipartUpload: calling handler <bound method RetryHandler.needs_retry of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryHandler object at 0x7fd703b8e080>>
2020-08-07 20:22:29,771 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 - botocore.retries.standard - DEBUG - Not retrying request.
2020-08-07 20:22:29,772 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.CompleteMultipartUpload: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7fd703bc7d68>>
2020-08-07 20:22:29,772 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.CompleteMultipartUpload: calling handler <function enhance_error_msg at 0x7fd703f90510>
```

Comment: You should maybe consider using multipart upload: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html.

Comment: `--expected-size` is only required when streaming data, so that can be removed. With such large files, network issues are increasingly likely. What type of Internet connection are you using (home, corporate)? Does it work if you run the command manually?

Comment: Marko - it automatically does multipart for files over 2gb based on my config.

Comment: John - I'm running this on a micro ec2 AWS instance. It works manually, and doesn't seem to get stuck in the upload loop